# Reuse a function docstring inside a class method

Tags: python

I have two folders: `a` and `b`. In folder `a`, I have a function called `fun1`. In folder `b` I have a class called `class1`. Inside `class1` there is a method named `meth1`. The method `meth1` returns `fun1` from folder `a`

How I can use the docstring of `fun1` in `meth1` without rewriting again the docstring?

What I tried is as below but it did not work.

folder `a`

```
def fun1():
    """
    docstring of fun1
    """
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

folder `b`

```
from a import fun1
class class1:
    def meth1(self):
        self.meth1.__dic__ = fun1.__doc__
        return fun1
     ...
     ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have to bring the bad news, but your idea is wrong. If `meth1` is returning `fun1`, then it should not have the same docstring (one will say e.g. _"returns a function"_ and the other won't). If `meth1` is in fact just always calling `fun1`, then you should not have `meth1` at all. If `meth1` is only sometimes calling `fun1`, then again it shoud not have the same docstring. *To sum it up:* `meth1` should either have a different docstring, or it should not exist in the first place.

Comment: I have functions outside the class since thet are quite large and doing a lot of mathematical operation. I call them in the class to create a GUI for end-user. The example I provided above is very simplified. Thanks for your input. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need a helper:

```
def func1():
    """
    docstring of fun1
    """
    pass

def doc_setter(origin):
    def wrapper(func):
        func.__doc__ = origin.__doc__
        return func
    return wrapper

class class1:

    @doc_setter(func1)
    def meth1(self):
        return func1
```

Answer (score 2):

It also can be an option (but variant with helper is better):

```
class class1:
    def meth1(self):
        return fun1

class1.meth1.__doc__ = fun1.__doc__
```